# How to save entity using @Transactional from Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

Have a simple Spring-Hibernate application with the following config:

App context:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.hibtests" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>org.hibtests.domain.Person</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb" />
    <property name="username" value="dbuser" />
    <property name="password" value="blahblah" />
</bean>


<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<context:annotation-config />
```

The main application looks like

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("simpleappcontext.xml");
PersonService personService = (PersonService) context.getBean("personService");

Person person = new Person();
person.setName("Alba");
person.setEmail("alba@gmail.com");
personService.addPerson(person);
```

with the `PersonService` being annotated `@Transactional`:

```
package org.hibtests.service;

@Transactional
@Component
public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonDao personDao;

    public PersonDao getPersonDao() {
        return personDao;
    }


    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public void addPerson(Person person) {
        getPersonDao().insert(person);
    }
}
```

PersonDao.java:

```
package org.hibtests.dao;

@Repository
public class PersonDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void insert(Person person) {
        Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(person);
    }
```

produces the error

```
INFO: Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@1fe4169] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: persist is not valid without active transaction
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:348)
    at $Proxy16.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibtests.dao.PersonDao.insert(PersonDao.java:26)
    at org.hibtests.dao.PersonService.addPerson(PersonService.java:27)
    at org.hibtests.dao.PersonService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$403bca40.invoke(<generated>)
```

while I could use `session.beginTransaction()` and `session.getTransaction().commit()` before and after the `persist` method, is it possible to just use Spring's `@Transactional` annotations to manage the transaction? If so how?

Comment: Is your service placed in the <context:component-scan base-package="org.hibtests" /> package?

Comment: Yes it is, all classes are covered by the `org.hibtests` scan. DI is occurring successfully - I checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
</props>
</property>
```

It is your own configuration that is breaking proper transaction support/integration. When using Spring for declarative transaction management never mess around with the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` property. Unless you are using JTA then you need to integrate it with JTA.

Spring by default registers its own `CurrentSessionContext` implementation for proper transaction integration with hibernate. It will register the `SpringSessionContext`. However as soon as you start configuring the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` this default will be overridden and as such transactions break.

Remove the line from your configuration.

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
</props>
</property>
```

This will properly let spring register its own contextual session management.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your insert method so Spring injects a transaction:

```
@Transactional
public void insert(Person person) {
```

And you PersonDao class should be implementing an interface. The "proxy" exception means Spring can't inject the transaction without an (annotated) interface. You need to add an interface an have PersonDao implement the interface.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Update your service class as follows

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true,propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public class PersonService {
}
```

OR you can do this way also

```
package org.hibtests.service;

@Service
public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonDao personDao;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true,propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public PersonDao getPersonDao() {
        return personDao;
    }


    @Transactional(readOnly = true,propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public void addPerson(Person person) {
        getPersonDao().insert(person);
    }
}
```

hope this will help you

Comment: try to run without transaction-manager="transactionManager" in <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> as <tx:annotation-driven />